# When phone calls stop you from jumping through car windows, there's something wrong

Tags: saints-row-the-third

I am growing extremely tired of running up to a car, right before jumping through the windshield/passenger/driver side window and as I'm hitting the button to get in... I get a phone call, and hit the button. Instead of jumping, I answer the call. Waiting around for the call to finish after such a let-down is such a drag!

Is there any way to prevent this from happening? A way to toggle the phone's ringer would be nice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there's no way to turn the "ringer" off on the phone.  Generally when it rings your gang is inviting you to a "Survival" mission, and you should probably go.  The survival missions spawn somewhat randomly, and they're required for the Saintsbook challenges (which is tied to an achievement).  They'll only call every so often (not more frequently than 10-20 minutes or so, although that's still [under investigation](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/39841/is-there-any-way-to-force-a-survival-challenge-to-start)) and they won't call when you're on a mission or otherwise engaged in an activity.

If you're not interested in the activity or its associated challenge/achievement, you can always ignore the call, or go to the site and immediately leave the radius, which will cancel the survival mission.

As soon as you answer the phone, you can go back to whatever you were doing previously with that button - you don't have to wait for the call to end.  Apparently the leader of the Saints sprung for a hands-free headset between Saints Row 2 and 3.

Comment: So, basically, I just have some *REALLY* bad timing? Also, even with the hands-free set, I still can't seem to make my character do anything while answering these calls... Any special trick to it?

Comment: Yeah, that's basically it.  I don't know what to tell you about your character during calls - I generally take them and then jack a car to get wherever I'm going due to the call.  I've never waited until it was finished.