# Saints Row 3 survival challenge

Tags: saints-row-the-third

In Saints Row the Third, Is it possible to complete the survival challenges after all the territories have been taken over?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it's possible to do this after taking all territories and/or completing the story. I had to finish up quite a few of them after everything else since they can take some time to pop up.

[More info and tips on survival challenges](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/39841/is-there-any-way-to-force-a-survival-challenge-to-start)